# How should I define icons for a large ListView list (+100 items)

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have been trying to create a ListView and I have succeded in creating one. However my ListView now uses the same icon for every item in the list. When I have been searching for answers people have just showed examples of lists with less than 10 items. But my list contains well over a 100 items.

For the text I just created a string-array in my string.xml, and retrieved them using

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] list_of_names = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
```

But how do I do the same with icons? Can/Should I define them in a separate file, just like i did with my string-array? My icons are in my drawables folder.

Also, should I even use an array of images for my list icons? Is there another way?

Thanks for help!

Edit:

CustomAdapter.java

```java
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] listNames) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_copy, listNames);
}

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_copy, parent, false);

        String item = getItem(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        textView.setText(item);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_red);
        return customView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] listNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), listNames);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

This creates a list with the same icon for all items, but the icons should be different.

And if it makes any difference, I have followed this tutorial from The New Boston: http://youtu.be/nOdSARCVYic?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl

Comment: If they all use the same icon just set it in the LisView item layout. The only reason to set it with an array is if the icons are different. If there are a number of different icons you could create a method to determine which type of icon to use and call it from getView

Comment: The icons are all different, I also edited my post to include code of my `customAdapter.java` and parts of my `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define inside strings.xml so:

```
<array name="drawerIcons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_action_design</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_action_develop</item>
</array>
```

You can add it to your ArrayList so:

```
ArrayList<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final String[] drawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer);
    final TypedArray drawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawerIcons);
    for (int i = 0; i < drawerTitles.length; i++) {
        drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(drawerTitles[i], drawerIcons.getDrawable(i)));
    }
```

And this is the DrawerItem class that I am using in my Navigation Drawer List View:

```
    public class DrawerItem {
    String title;
    Drawable icon;

    public DrawerItem(String title, Drawable icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

You should change your arralist (string). Create the ArrayList using the code of DrawerItems (if you want multiple textview and imageview, you can add more elements to that class.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought about defining my drawables like that inside the strings.xml so I did that. However I did not really know where to add the code you wrote. I tried fiddling with it for a while. I edited my post with the original code for my customAdapter and the relevant code from my MainActivity file.

Comment: @traktor the xml goes in a res/arrays.xml file

Comment: @zgc7009, well in my example Really I am using all arrays inside strings.xml. OP should use arrays.xml instead of strings.xml